# Laravel Livewire how to validate array data

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I try to validate array when form submitted as

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy="data.name" placeholder="name">
```

```php
    //at livewire component class
    $data = [
        'name' => 'someValue',
        'phone' => 'someValue',
        'email' => 'someValue'
    ]
```

I try this

```php
    Validator::make($this->data,[
      'name' => 'required',
       ...
    ])->validate();
```

but not working, please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can validate using the same syntax as you have used in `wire:model`:

```
$this->validate([
    'data.name' => ['required'],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you it work to display the error too I have to do this on blade  `@error('data.name') ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm new using Livewire, Idk if this related to your question. But, since your question is on top in Google. Maybe this will help other people.

```
public function saveAdd()
{
  $rules_state = [
    'state_name' => 'required',
    'state_email' => 'required',
  ];
  $check_state = $this->inputsFormAddProduct;
  foreach ($this->inputsFormAddProduct as $key => $value) {
    $rules_state = array_merge($rules_state, [
      'state_product.'.$value => 'required',
      'state_qty.'.$value => 'required',
    ]);
  }
  $validatedData = $this->validate($rules_state,
    [
        'required' => 'The :attribute cannot be empty.',
    ],
  );
  dd($rules_state);
}
```